# Externalized grails.serverURL not accessible from Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an application where the config is externalized. In Config.groovy, I'm updating

```
grails.config.locations=[file:/.../myapp-log4j.groovy, file:/.../myapp-config.properties]
```

That works fine for datasources and such. But later in Config.groovy, I have:

```
springws {
    wsdl {
        MyApp {
            // In this case the wsdl will be available at    <grails.serverURL>/services/v1/myapp/myapp-v1.wsdl
            wsdlName= 'myapp-v1'
            xsds= '/WEB-INF/myapp.xsd'
            portTypeName = 'myappPort'
            serviceName = 'myappService'
            locationUri = "${grails.serverURL}/services/v1/myapp"
            targetNamespace = 'http://www..../myapp/v1/definitions'
        }
    }
}
```

And ${grails.serverURL} contains [:] which is not what is in my config file. The config file contains (among the datasource details):

```
grails.serverURL=http://samiel:9011/xid
```

My guess would be that the updated grails.config.locations is only used after I return from Config.groovy.

So, what are my options to setup my web service details based on the externalized serverURL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get when I run your example (just confirming your starting postion):

```
def testExternalConfig() {
  println "grails.serverURL: ${ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.serverURL}"
  println "springws.wsdl.MyApp.locationUri ${ConfigurationHolder.config.springws.wsdl.MyApp.locationUri}"
}

--Output from testExternalConfig--
grails.serverURL: http://samiel:9011/xid
springws.wsdl.MyApp.locationUri http://localhost:8080/soGrails/services/v1/myapp
```

Like you said, Config.groovy does not see the value set in the external config. I believe that Grails processes external
configs after Config.groovy, and this test appears to confirm that. The logic being that you likely have external config file
values that you want to have precedence over config in war file.

Fix is to override the full property in myapp-config.properties:

```
grails.serverURL=http://samiel:9011/xid
springws.wsdl.MyApp.locationUri=http://samiel:9011/xid/services/v1/myapp
```

With that change I get this:

```
--Output from testExternalConfig--
grails.serverURL: http://samiel:9011/xid
springws.wsdl.MyApp.locationUri http://samiel:9011/xid/services/v1/myapp
```